# Is it: 'They and I?' Or: 'Them and I?' Or: 'Them and me?' Or something else?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, expressions

This is purely for communication via online social media for the proper use of a phrase which I am unsure of its proper structure;

which of the following is proper use:
1.) They and I,
2.) Them and I,
3.) Them and me?

For example: "the only difference between ... and ... is this"

If there's something I'm missing could someone please inform me?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you want to use the phrase.  If it is a subject, you should say *they and I.*  If it is an object, you should say *them and me.*

The example you gave should be *the only difference between them and me is this,* because *them and me* is the object of the preposition *between.*

By contrast, you should say *they and I agree with you that the party should be next weekend,* because *they and I* is the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it it them and me.

“The only difference between them and me is xyz”